# Python aggregate data large file in GB, stack data

Tags: python, aggregate

My data (~ size in GB) looks like:

```
1  11
2  44
1  66
3  88
1  77
2  55
...
```

And I want the results to be:

```
1 11 66 77
2 44 55
3 88
```

I tried using a dictionary, but the max speed is 80k rows/min. And I have 16m rows of those....

Is there any better solution here?

My code:

```
data=open(file)
d={};seen=[]
for line in data:
    if line[0] not in seen:
         d[line[0]]=line[1]
         seen.append(line[0])
    else:
         d[line[0]].append(line[1])
pickle.dump(d,file.name)
```

Comment: Wslcome to the stack overflow. What is the database management syatem? If you post your codes you have already tried then it is easy to us to give better solution.

Comment: thanks for the comments. code posted. I do not use db, but simply save file as txt or csv.

Answer (score 2):

The wonderful tool `defaultdict` helps here. It acts like a dictionary, but you can append to each value -- a list -- and the list will spontaneously be created.

## print values grouped by first column

```
input = '''1 11
2 44
1 66
3 88
1 77
2 55'''.split('\n')

import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for line in input:
    id_, value = line.split()
    data[id_].append(value)

for key,values in data.iteritems():
    print key, ' '.join(values)
```

## output

```
1 11 66 77
3 88
2 44 55
```

Note that the output isn't sorted.   Given the input is big, it would take extra memory to sort the input values.  If this is desired, change the code to `for key,values in sorted(data.iteritems()):`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Pandas? I think Pandas can read files much faster, and do computations at a much faster rate than ordinary Python. Something like the following may be useful ...

```
temp = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['a', 'b'])
print temp.groupby('a').agg( lambda xs: ' '.join( map(str, xs)  )  ).reset_index()
```

will print the following:

```
   a         b
0  1  11 66 77
1  2     44 55
2  3        88
```

Give it a try ...